# Linux executable file format. Where is the specification?

Tags: linux, assembly, executable, elf, executable-format

I want to understand how Linux executable file is consisted of. Where can I get the specification?

I compiled a simple assemble file with gcc but the generated file size is much bigger than I expected.

```
# cat tmp.s
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global main
main:
        mov rax, 42
        ret
# gcc -o tmp tmp.s
# ./tmp
# echo $?
42

# ls -l tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8136 Jul 31 04:03 tmp

# xxd tmp
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0300 3e00 0100 0000 f004 0000 0000 0000  ..>.............
...
...
00001fb0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001fc0: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........

# uname -a
Linux fb8275f9e7a0 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Google ELF, executable and linking format.

Comment: Re: file size: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html.  Also current toolchains align sections to page boundaries, making them bigger than necessary.  **`file tmp` would have told you it's an ELF executable**.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elf/info, and try `readelf -a tmp`

Comment: @daniu Thanks. As you said, Wikipedia shows the specs. I'm checking about IA-32 spec.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. readelf is very useful to understand ELF. And thanks for telling about teensy ELF.

Comment: Please note that ELF is not the only executable file used by Linux: The first Linux versions seemed to use the AOUT format instead of ELF; some Linux versions use COFF.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Thank you for mentioning about that. I did not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file tmp` would have told you it's an **ELF executable**. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elf/info, and try `readelf -a tmp`

re: file size: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html.

Also current toolchains align sections to page boundaries, making them bigger than necessary.  Link with `ld --nmagic` to disable section alignment entirely (possibly breaking compiler-generated code).  Also disables linking with shared libraries.  Anyway, that's why your executable is just over 2x 4kiB when most of it is padding.